# Determining continuity of $f$ where $f(x) = 0$ for irrational $x$ and $f(x) = 1/q$ if $x = p/q$ where $p,q$ are relatively prime integers and $q>0$

Tags: real-analysis

This is from Folland's Advanced Calculus, Exercise 1.3.7.

This is my attempt:

==

First, let $x$ be rational; then $f(x) = 1/q$ is also rational. From Exercise 1.3.6, $\mathbb{I}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and following the same argument as before, we can construct a sequence of irrational numbers $\{a_n\}$ that converges to $x$, and so $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) = 0 \ne f(x)$, meaning that $f$ is not continuous for rational $x$.

Second, let $x$ be irrational. Then $f(x) = 0$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and consider the inequality $|a-x| < \delta$. We wish to show that choosing $\delta$ appropriately will mean that $|f(a) - f(x)| = |f(a)| < \epsilon$. Suppose that $a$ is irrational; then $f(a) = 0$ and $\delta$ can be chosen arbitrarily because $|f(a)| = 0 < \epsilon$ no matter what. Suppose, alternatively, that $a$ is rational; let $a = p/q$ where $q>0$ and $p,q$ are relatively prime. Then $f(a) = 1/q$, so we must choose $\delta$ so that $1/q < \epsilon$ given $|p/q - x| < \delta$. (Unsure how to complete this part.)

Third, we see that $f(x)$ for nonzero $x$ is either 0 or $x/p$ for a nonzero integer $p$, meaning that $|f(x) - f(0)| = |f(x)| < |x|$. Let $\epsilon_0$ and choose $\delta = \epsilon$; then when $|x| < \delta$ we have $|f(x)| < \delta = \epsilon$. This demonstrates that $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$.

==

I would appreciate a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions are both discontinuous at the rationals.  The $0-1$ function is discontinuous at the irrationals, so everywhere.  But the function at this question is not.

Suppose you have an irrational $x$ and you want to use an $\varepsilon,\delta$ argument.

Given $\varepsilon$ there are only a finite number of rationals of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ in the interval $[x-1,x+1]$ which are *basic* enough to have $q \lt \frac1\varepsilon$, and none of the these are equal to $x$. So let $\delta$ be half the absolute distance from $x$ to the closest of these *basic* rationals.

Any $y$ in $[x-\delta,x+\delta]$ will then have $|f(y)-f(x)|=f(y)\lt \varepsilon.$